# "Subquery returns more than 1 row" when use select to set value of parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an issue when I try to set the value of a variable with a subquery.

This is my SQL code:

```
SELECT @V_SOURCE = (SELECT ITEM_SOURCE
                    FROM TABLE1
                    WHERE OPP_CODE = @V_OPP_CODE
                      AND PDGROUPNO = @V_PRD_GROUP_NO
                      AND DELETE_FLAG IS NULL
                      AND CONTRACTOR = @V_CONTRACTOR
                      AND OPP_ITEM_NO = @_OPP_ITEM_NO)
```

When I run this code with an assumed variable that is used in WHERE condition, it returns only 1 row and 1 col that is correct but if I run this code with store procedure it will return the error:

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression

Comment: Try select @cnt = (select count(*) FROM ... and see how many rows it tries to return.

Comment: The parameters you are providing results in more than 1 row... you need to handle that in some way. Either its an error condition with the parameters, in which case throw and error. Or its valid and you need additional filtering to return the correct row. Either way without sample data and desired results and your logic explained we cannot help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sub-query can return multiple rows.
Even if it shouldn't, that won't do.

But you can change it to this.

```
SELECT @V_SOURCE = ITEM_SOURCE
FROM TABLE1
WHERE OPP_CODE = @V_OPP_CODE
  AND PDGROUPNO = @V_PRD_GROUP_NO
  AND DELETE_FLAG IS NULL
  AND CONTRACTOR = @V_CONTRACTOR
  AND OPP_ITEM_NO = @_OPP_ITEM_NO
GROUP BY ITEM_SOURCE;
```

It'll assign the last value of the resultset to the variable.
Which is fine, since you expect only one anyway.

Another way is to pick only the top 1

```
SET @V_SOURCE = (
     SELECT TOP 1 ITEM_SOURCE
     FROM TABLE1
     WHERE OPP_CODE = @V_OPP_CODE
       AND PDGROUPNO = @V_PRD_GROUP_NO
       AND DELETE_FLAG IS NULL
       AND CONTRACTOR = @V_CONTRACTOR
       AND OPP_ITEM_NO = @_OPP_ITEM_NO
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I find an issue in my query because of I query data to use for this query some CONTRACTOR is NULL then it makes an error when using this query

```
SELECT @V_SOURCE = (SELECT ITEM_SOURCE
                FROM TABLE1
                WHERE OPP_CODE = @V_OPP_CODE
                  AND PDGROUPNO = @V_PRD_GROUP_NO
                  AND DELETE_FLAG IS NULL
                  AND CONTRACTOR = @V_CONTRACTOR
                  AND OPP_ITEM_NO = @_OPP_ITEM_NO)
```

When I filter data that CONTRACTOR is NULL out, I don't get any error now.